# Devise - Nested Attributes - Customer --> Customer_addresses --> Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I have been trying to create a relationship like the database listed below, using devise to create the Customer table. I have created migrations for the other tables using the ID ing though table-names and ID. My models look like the below. I know I have gone overboard with the has_many relationships, but I have been trying this all day.

Can anyone help or show the correct way to set up this so that I can create, edit and update addresses on the user. I have managed success with simple nested attributes say Customer/ Direct to address but when I place the table in the middle I just cant get the address attributes to show or update.

I guess there is a more complex edit, create , destroy method that needs to be implemented also.

I'm also getting lost with how to allow strong params on this type of nesting as most examples i can find only have it connected to tables that hold the user_id in them and not one that is connected through another table.

cheers in advance for the guidance.

[DataModel image here](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/customers_and_addresses/index.htm)

Tables
**customers** / Devise table defaults

**customer_addresses**
id
address_id
address_type_id
customer_id

**addresses**
id
address   xzy Marua Road 
other details / Front house

**address_type**
id
address_type             / Home , Business etc
address_type_description / Where you live etc

```html
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :customer_addresses
has_many :addresses
has_many :address_types

accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer_addresses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address_types
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class UserAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :customer
has_many :address_types
has_many :addresses
end

class AddressType < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :customer_address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user_address
end
```

```html
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :user_addresses do |ff| %>
        <div>
          <%= ff.label :address_id %><br />
          <%= ff.text_field :address_id %>
            <%= ff.fields_for :address do |fff| %>
              <%= fff.label :address %><br />
              <%= fff.text_field :address %>
          <% end %>
    <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>

user controller params

 def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:id, :username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                            user_address_attributes:[:user_is, :address_id, :address_type_id],
                            addresses_attributes:[:id, :address, :other_address_details ],
                            address_type_attributes:[ :id, :address_type])
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The associations you defined should have been like the following

```
class Customer
  has_many :customer_addresses
  has_many :addresses, :through => :customer_addresses
  has_many :address_types, :through => :customer_addresses
end

class Address
  has_many :customer_addresses
  has_many :customers, :through => :customer_addresses
  has_many :address_types, :through => :customer_addresses
end

class AddressType
  has_many :customer_addresses
  has_many :customers, :through => :customer_addresses
  has_many :addresses, :through => :customer_addresses
end

class CustomerAddress
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :address_type
end
```

Comment: Still having issues getting through to the address field. But further than before.

Comment: Have added form snippet. gets address_id if from user_address table but can seem to get it to go the next step and pull from the address table.

Comment: getting close. Have it connected to form now and showing stored info :-))) massive improvement. Just cant get it to save. Needed to add a user_addresses_id column to the address table.

Comment: Awesome stuff go it to work. I'll past a full version in the morning. Cheers for the push in the right direction. :-) tried to upvote but says I need more rep.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :customer_addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer_addresses

end

class AddressType
  has_many :customer_addresses

end

class CustomerAddress

 belongs_to :address_type
 belongs_to :customer
 belongs_to :address

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

 after_initialize :add_address, unless: 'address.present?'

 def add_address
    self.build_address
 end 

end
```